# ggplot histogram and distribution same levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to plot histogram and density of values in the same plot and same levels:
that is that density plot should be as "high" as histogram

```
library(ggplot2)
LONG <- c(runif(20000,-10.8544921875,-9.021484375))
LONG = data.frame(LONG)
ggplot(LONG, aes(LONG, ..count..)) + geom_histogram(fill = "steelblue") + 
  geom_density()
```

Is not working and density is much more bigger than I want it to be

Comment: This does not answer my question _ I want Histogram to be "High" to aprox. 700 units and Density plot to have same height and be in the same scale as Histogram in example script.

Comment: Not a duplicate question - I want to account also for scalling.

Comment: I tried Ramnath's solution in the linked question and it shows the empirical density in the "same scale as the histogram". What exactly does not meet your requirements? The density will always be smoother than the bars, so its max value will not be exactly the max value of the bars.
If you want arbitrary scaling, multiply `..density..` by a factor that suits you in the `aes()` definition.

Comment: You can only match the kde and histogram if you know the binwidth of the histogram, e.g. `binwidth <- 0.1`. Then, you could plot as follows: `ggplot(LONG, aes(LONG)) + geom_histogram(fill = "steelblue", binwidth = binwidth) + 
  geom_density(aes(y = stat(count) * binwidth))`